# Bash paths calculation

Tags: linux, bash

1. I would like to know why in order to get current directory from within a script we need to use solution such as:`DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"` taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within).
   Instead of something like:
   `DIR=$("pwd")`
2. Once I have current directory of current script, and I want to calculate its `parent's parent parent` directory path, how do I do that?
   In terminal its simply `cd ../../../`, how this can be caluclated on `DIR` and assigned to a new variable?
3. What is the difference in bash assignment between `NUM:=1` and `NUM=1`

Cheers

Comment: You should ask 3 questions as 3 separate questions. Which answer will you flag as correct if there are 3 different answers, one for each question?

Comment: The link you give literally answers question 1 does it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That's not the current directory, but the directory where the script is located. Other similar solutions are `readlink -f "${0%/*}"` etc.
2. You can add the double dots to the DIR:

   ```
   great_grand_parent=$DIR/../../..
   ```

   Call `readlink` or do the magic with `cd` to get rid of the double dots.
3. `NUM:=1` is not an assignment at all.

Comment: Thanks. About 3, what is it?

Comment: `bash: NUM:=1: command not found`. So unless you have an executable file of such a name, it's a syntax error.

Comment: Ok my mistake lets ask it for `SOME_PATH:=/var/log` vs `SOME_PATH=/var/log`

Comment: By the way as for question 1, can you please explain a bit the difference between my suggestion and solution from other thread? I'm not sure I understand the difference

Comment: @JavaSa That's still not an assignment: "-bash: SOME_PATH:=/var/log: No such file or directory".

Comment: By the way solution 2 doesn't work for me, are you sure it works?

Comment: @JavaSa: Your suggestion returns the current directory, the other solution returns the directory where the script is located.

Comment: @JavaSa: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What's in $DIR, what's in the other variable?